# $\mathbb{Z}[G^{n+1}] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}[G^n]$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $G$ be a group. If $M$ is any right $G$-module, then we can consider $M$ as left $G$-module also under the action $g.m:= mg^{-1}$, where $m \in M$ and $g \in G$. Consider $\mathbb{Z}[G^{n+1}]$ as right $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module under the action $( g_0,g_1, \ldots, g_n).g=( g_0g,g_1g, \ldots, g_ng)$. Then it is true that $\mathbb{Z}[G^{n+1}] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}[G^n]$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module. One can prove this using properties of tensor product but I want to see it explicitly.

> My attempt is as follows

Define a map 
$ \phi: \mathbb{Z}[G^{n+1}]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}[G^{n}]$ as $$\phi(( g_0,g_1, \ldots, g_n)\otimes 1)= ( g_0 g_n^{-1},g_1 g_n^{-1}, \ldots, g_{n-1}g_n^{-1}).$$

The inverse of the above map is given by $( g_0,g_1, \ldots, g_{n-1}) \mapsto ( g_0,g_1, \ldots, g_{n-1},1) \otimes 1.$

> I want to know whether the above maps are correct or not? And are there any other maps to see the above isomorphisms, as I am not getting the desired result using these maps?

---

I should explain the problem too:

Let $a=\big((g_1,g_2) \otimes 1 \big)\otimes g \in  (\mathbb{Z}[G^2] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} \mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[G]$.

Now If I use the above isomorphism, then $a=a_1=(g_1g_2^{-1}g,g) \in \mathbb{Z}[G^2]$, where as if I use the associativity of tensor products then $a=a_2=(g_1g,g_2g) \in \mathbb{Z}[G^2]$, and clearly $a_1 \neq a_2,$ unless $g_2=e$.

> I want to understand why this is happening?

Comment: Just to clarify things, is the $\mathbb Z[G]$-module structure of $\mathbb Z$ defined by $g\cdot n=0,\,\forall n\in \mathbb Z,\,g\in G$?

Comment: awllower: Yes, $\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial $G$-module.

Comment: If $\mathbb Z$ is a trivial $G$-module don't we have $$ (g_0,\dots,g_n)\otimes 1 = (1,g_1g_0^{-1}\dots,g_n g_0^{-1})\cdot g_0 \otimes 1 = (1,g_1g_0^{-1},\dots,g_n g_0^{-1})\otimes 0=0?$$

Comment: $(g_0,\ldots,g_n) \otimes 1 = (g_0 g_n^{-1}, g_1 g_n^{-1}, \ldots, g_{n-1}g_n^{-1}) .g_n \otimes 1=  (g_0 g_n^{-1}, g_1 g_n^{-1}, \ldots, g_{n-1}g_n^{-1}) \otimes g_n .1=(g_0 g_n^{-1}, g_1 g_n^{-1}, \ldots, g_{n-1} g_n^{-1}) \otimes 1$

Comment: user347489: $\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial $G$ modules so $g.n=n, \forall g \in G$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @eyp got it! I was just blindly following the first comment saying $g\cdot n=0$. This makes much more sense.

Comment: You seem to be implying a $\mathbb Z$-module isomorphism $\mathbb Z[G]\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z[G]\cong \mathbb Z[G^2]$. How is that given?

Comment: Christoph: Let $\bar{\mathbb{Z}[G]}:= \mathbb{Z}[G]$ as trivial $G$-module and consider right $G$-action on $\bar{\mathbb{Z}[G]} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[G]$ as $(\alpha \otimes 1).g= \alpha \otimes g$. Now we can see that $\bar{\mathbb{Z}[G]} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[G] \cong \mathbb{Z}[G^2]$ as $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules under the map $g_1 \otimes g_2 \mapsto (g_1g_2,g_2)$.

Comment: Christoph: I am considering $\bar{\mathbb{Z}[G]}$ because $\mathbb{Z}[G^2] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}[G]$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules but not  as $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules under the map $\phi$.

Comment: Since the tensor product is $G$-equivariant, the isomorphism follows by just always factoring the last element of the product into the right hand side. For example, considering $\mathbb{Z}[G^3] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} \mathbb{Z}$ we can rewrite any pure tensor $(a,b,c)\otimes 1 = (ac^{-1}, bc^{-1}, 1) \otimes 1$, where the $c$ has travelled over the tensor product and disappeared because $c \cdot 1 = 1$.

Comment: @Joppy: I have used exactly the same map, but the answer is not consistent with the associativity of the tensor products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isomorphism is fine; in fact, you can use any of the $n+1$ positions, giving $n+1$ different isomorphisms
$$\alpha_i\colon \mathbb Z[G^{n+1}]\otimes_{\mathbb Z[G]}\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z[G^n], \quad (g_0,\ldots,g_n) \mapsto (g_0g_i^{-1},\ldots,g_ng_i^{-1}). $$

Your problem is that you have messed up the bimodule structure. You are considering $\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z[G]\cong\mathbb Z[G]$ as a $\mathbb Z[G]$-bimodule, but whereas it is the regular module with respect to the right action, it is actually the trivial module with respect to the left action. In other words, we have the actions $g\cdot y\cdot k=yk$ for $g,y,k\in G$.

So, in your problem at the end of the post, we can use $\alpha_0$ to obtain the isomorphism
$$ \mathbb Z[G^2]\otimes_{\mathbb Z[G]}\mathbb Z[G] \to \mathbb Z[G^2], \quad (g,h)\otimes k \mapsto (hg^{-1},k). $$
The $\mathbb Z[G^2]$-$\mathbb Z[G]$-bimodule action on $\mathbb Z[G^2]$ is then
$$ (g,h)\cdot (x,y)\cdot k := (hxg^{-1},yk). $$

Alternatively we can use $\alpha_1$ to get the map $(g,h)\otimes k \mapsto (gh^{-1},k)$, and the bimodule action is then
$$ (g,h)\cdot (x,y)\cdot k := (hxg^{-1},yk). $$

Comment: Andrew Hubery: Thank you. I got your point.

Comment: Andrew Hubery: If we take the map $\mathbb{Z}[G^2] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} \mathbb{Z}[G] \to \mathbb{Z}[G^2]$ as $(g,h) \otimes k \mapsto (gh^{-1}k,k)$, then it is a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module isomorphism under the given action( as in the question) of $G$ on $\mathbb{Z}[G^2]$.

Comment: Andrew Hubery: May I request you to please look at the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352118/to-understand-the-description-of-relative-group-homology-h-g-h-mathbbz. I have spent many days to sort it out but still no progress. I think there too I am doing something wrong with tensor products.